# Google Bubble Chart: How to use sizeAxis.maxSize and sizeAxis.minSize

Tags: charts, visualization

Creating a Google Bubble Chart and trying to reduce size of bubbles to reduce overlap.  I see in the doc sizeAxis.maxSize and sizeAxis.minSize can be useful for this but don't see any examples on how to use these - e.g. their syntax and whether they go under var options.  If someone can provide an example of their use, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing sizeAxis.maxSize and sizeAxis.minSize in use. They are indeed placed within the 'options' variable.

```
   function drawSeriesChart(graphdata) {
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(graphdata);

              var options = {
                hAxis: {title: 'Home PTGP'},
                vAxis: {title: 'Away PTGP'},
                colorAxis: {colors: ['yellow', 'red']},
                legend: 'none',
                sizeAxis:{maxSize:7,minSize:1}
              };

              var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

              chart.draw(data, options);
   }
```